# How to visualize voxels and show it on meshlab?

Tags: python, computer-vision, ply-file-format

I have a voxel coordinates tensor with shape (Number_voxel,4). The second dim just indicate the batch_id and coordinates of that voxel (batch_id,x,y,z).

How can I use this tensor to create voxels which can be seen on meshlab?

Currently, I use these codes, but the result is not good.

```
 import numpy as np
 import os
 from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement



def write_ply(points, face_data, filename, text=True):

  points = [(points[i,0], points[i,1], points[i,2]) for i in range(points.shape[0])]

  vertex = np.array(points, dtype=[('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'),('z', 'f4')])

  face = np.empty(len(face_data),dtype=[('vertex_indices', 'i4', (4,))])
  face['vertex_indices'] = face_data

  ply_faces = PlyElement.describe(face, 'face')
  ply_vertexs = PlyElement.describe(vertex, 'vertex', comments=['vertices'])
  PlyData([ply_vertexs, ply_faces], text=text).write(filename)

def occ2points(coordinates):
  points  = []
  len = coordinates.shape[0]
  for i in range(len):
    points.append(np.array([int(coordinates[i,1]),int(coordinates[i,2]),int(coordinates[i,3])]))
 
  return np.array(points)

def generate_faces(points):
  corners = np.zeros((8*len(points),3))
  faces = np.zeros((6*len(points),4))
  for index in range(len(points)):
    corners[index*8]= np.array([points[index,0]-0.5, points[index,1]-0.5, points[index,2]-0.5])
    corners[index*8+1]= np.array([points[index,0]+0.5, points[index,1]-0.5, points[index,2]-0.5])
    corners[index*8+2]= np.array([points[index,0]-0.5, points[index,1]+0.5, points[index,2]-0.5])
    corners[index*8+3]= np.array([points[index,0]+0.5, points[index,1]+0.5, points[index,2]-0.5])
    corners[index*8+4]= np.array([points[index,0]-0.5, points[index,1]-0.5, points[index,2]+0.5])
    corners[index*8+5]= np.array([points[index,0]+0.5, points[index,1]-0.5, points[index,2]+0.5])
    corners[index*8+6]= np.array([points[index,0]-0.5, points[index,1]+0.5, points[index,2]+0.5])
    corners[index*8+7]= np.array([points[index,0]+0.5, points[index,1]+0.5, points[index,2]+0.5])
    faces[index*6]= np.array([len(points)+8*index, len(points)+8*index+1,len(points)+8*index+2,len(points)+8*index+3])
    faces[index*6+1]= np.array([len(points)+8*index+4, len(points)+8*index+5,len(points)+8*index+6,len(points)+8*index+7])
    faces[index*6+2]= np.array([len(points)+8*index+2, len(points)+8*index+3,len(points)+8*index+6,len(points)+8*index+7])
    faces[index*6+3]= np.array([len(points)+8*index+0, len(points)+8*index+1,len(points)+8*index+4,len(points)+8*index+5])
    faces[index*6+4]= np.array([len(points)+8*index+0, len(points)+8*index+2,len(points)+8*index+4,len(points)+8*index+6])
    faces[index*6+5]= np.array([len(points)+8*index+1, len(points)+8*index+3,len(points)+8*index+5,len(points)+8*index+7])
return corners, faces

def writeocc(coordinates,save_path,filename):
  points = occ2points(coordinates)
  #print(points.shape)
  corners, faces = generate_faces(points)
  if points.shape[0] == 0:
      print('the predicted mesh has zero point!')
  else:
      points = np.concatenate((points,corners),axis=0)
      write_ply(points, faces, os.path.join(save_path,filename))
```

'''
Just like this picture:[visualization of voxel occupancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnuCr.jpg)
Thanks guys!

Comment: Please, describe if you want to visualice the voxels or you want build a surface interpolating those voxels using marching cubes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just visualize the voxels, I add a picture on the problem :)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are trying to create small cubes around the voxel center and storing in PLY file. That is probably the only way you can visualize voxel in MeshLab. Can you share how is it showing up for you or why you think the result is not good.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code just need a small change to ensure that faces are stored preserving coherency in the orientation.

Replace the definition of faces in your `generate_faces(points)`function with this:

```py
    base=len(points)+8*index
    faces[index*6]= np.array([base+2, base+3,base+1,base+0])
    faces[index*6+1]= np.array([base+4, base+5, base+7,base+6])
    faces[index*6+2]= np.array([base+3, base+2, base+6,base+7])
    faces[index*6+3]= np.array([base+0, base+1, base+5,base+4])
    faces[index*6+4]= np.array([base+2, base+0,base+4,base+6])
    faces[index*6+5]= np.array([base+1, base+3,base+7,base+5])
    
  return corners, faces
```

This is the result for a pair of voxels...

[image]

Comment: This perfectly solves my problem, thanks man!

Comment: No offence, but I'm a cat.